# Attachment Trigger Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

Can you please help me with Test Class regarding Attachment Trigger I have. Whenever I run Test Class I get this error below.
 System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
 Class.BillingCrapAttachment.InsertAttachment: line 8, column 1

Here is my Trigger

```
trigger Attachment on Attachment (After insert, after delete) {

 Set <Id> ParentId = New Set<Id>();
 If(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)
 {   
  for(Attachment AttObj : Trigger.New){
       ParentId.add(AttObj.ParentId);
  }
 if(ParentId.size()>0){
 List<Billing_Team_Request__c> B = [select id, Attachment__c,(Select Id from Attachments) from Billing_Team_Request__c where id =: Trigger.New[0].ParentId];
 if(B.size()>0){
                        if(B[0].Attachments.size()>0)
                        {
                                    B[0].Attachment__c = true;
                                    update B;
                        }  
}                        
}
}
  If(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete)
  {
   for(Attachment AttObj : Trigger.old){
       ParentId.add(AttObj.ParentId);
  }
 if(ParentId.size()>0){
    List<Billing_Team_Request__c> B = [select id, Attachment__c,(Select Id from Attachments) from Billing_Team_Request__c where id =: Trigger.Old[0].ParentId];
    if(B.size()>0){    
    if(B[0].Attachments.size()==0)
                        {
                                    B[0].Attachment__c = false;
                                    update B;
                        }                      
  }
  }
  }
    }
```

Here is my Test Class

```
@isTest
    public class BillingCrapAttachment { 

        //Method
        static testMethod void InsertAttachment() {

        Billing_Team_Request__c b = new Billing_Team_Request__c();
        b.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Account_Number_Issue';  ****//I think issue is here. Should I use RecordTypeID or RecordTypeName here?****
        b.Customer_Contact_Name__c = '0034000001c7sJa';   **// I think issue is here (Customer Contact Name is my Lookup of Contact. Should I use Production Contact ID here or Sandbox Contact ID here?**
        b.Status__c = 'Pending Submission';
        insert b;

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();

        attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        attach.body=bodyBlob;
        attach.parentId=b.id;
        insert attach;

        List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:b.id];
        System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());

         attach = [SELECT Id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:b.id];

            delete attach;  

            b.Attachment__c = False;
            update b;      


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these lines look potentially problematic:

```
b.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Account_Number_Issue';  
b.Customer_Contact_Name__c = '0034000001c7sJa';
```

For the first, use SOQL to fetch the record type id based on object type and assign it, e.g.

```
RecordType rt = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Account_Number_Issue' and SobjectType = 'Billing_Team_Request__c' LIMIT 1];
b.RecordTypeId = rt.id;
```

For the second, I would refrain from naming Lookup fields "Name," as these tend to be disparate things in Salesforce. Name typically refers to some non-unique String value. If it's a lookup, you assign it an id using SOQL similar to the first example.

Comment: I have updated my test class as below but getting this error now. System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject. Class.BillingCrapAttachment.InsertAttachment: line 8, column 1                                                        
        
        RecordType rt = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Account_Number_Issue' and SobjectType = 'Billing_Team_Request__c' LIMIT 1];
        Contact con = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Test Contact 2' LIMIT 1];
        b.RecordTypeId = rt.id;
        b.Customer_Contact_Name__c = con.id;

Comment: Fix either the Name or SObjectType parameter in the first SOQL query. One or more is incorrect